# How to render to a TIFF Float 32 output

Tags: rendering, file-format

How do we render to TIFF Float 32 output? I.e. 32 bits per channel (NOT 32 bits per pixel) TIFF file.

Blender UI only seems to give me the option of choosing between 8 bit and 16 bit for TIFF.

The workaround it seems is rendering in OpenEXR and then converting the files to TIFF Float 32 outside of Blender, but I would rather not do this if possible because even using macro will take some time for a lot frames.

Context:

I need to render animations into individual frames, TIFF 32

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment, at least from the UI, unless there is some workaround by forcing anything through python, but I doubt that

Comment: I'm willing to consider if anybody can provide a guide.